# Recursive Function return ordered vector

Tags: c, recursion, substring, c-strings, function-definition

I have a problem with the return of that function, it should return the vector with the typed sequence, but it's returning an ordered sequence, could you tell me where I'm going wrong?

Create a recursive function that takes a string as input and also its length. This function should return how many times the character the substring “hi” appears in the string.

**Prohibited**

The first line in the input contains the number n of test cases. Next, n lines occur, each containing a string of maximum length equal to 5000 characters

**Exit**

The output consists of n lines, each containing an integer that indicates the number of times the string “hi” occurs in the input string. All strings are written in lowercase letters.

*Example*

**Prohibited**

```
4
hipotenuse hipothermia hilux hifi
hi
hihihi
xavante hey
```

**Exit**

```
4
1
3
0
```

**My code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 5000

int ocorrencias(const char *palavra, size_t len) {
    char *st = "hi";
    return len ?
        (*st == *palavra) + ocorrencias(palavra + 1, len - 1) :
        0;
}

int main() {
    int n,i;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    char palavra[MAX];
    int re[n];
    for(i=0; i<=n; i++){
        fgets(palavra, MAX, stdin);
        re[i] = ocorrencias(palavra, strlen(palavra));
    }
    for(i=0; i<=n; i++){
        printf("%d\n", re[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have not understood why the output for the first string is 4.

Comment: the translation did this, in portuguese hypotenuse and hyporthermia are spelled with hi, already fixed

Comment: You are searching "hi" not "hy". The compiler knows nothing that "hy" is the same as "hi". See your own code char *st = "hi";

Comment: Corner cases: Off by 2.  "each containing a string of maximum length equal to 5000 characters" ---> This count of characters likely does not include the line's `'\n'` nor the `'\0'` appended to form a string.  Suggest `char palavra[MAX]; ...  fgets(palavra, MAX, stdin);` -->  `char palavra[MAX + 2]; ...  fgets(palavra, sizeof palavra, stdin);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters the for loops like this

```
for(i=0; i<=n; i++){
         ^^^^^
```

are wrong.

You need to write

```
for(i=0; i < n; i++){
         ^^^^^^
```

The function `ocorrencias` should be declared either like

```
size_t ocorrencias( const char *palavra );
```

or like

```
size_t ocorrencias( const char *palavra, const char *st );
```

instead of

```
int ocorrencias(const char *palavra, size_t len) ;
```

because it deals with strings and the function is able to determine lengths of passed strings.

It can be defined for example the following way

```
size_t ocorrencias( const char *palavra ) 
{
    const char *st = "hi";
    const char *p = strstr( palavra, st );
 
    return p == NULL ? 0 : 1 + ocorrencias( p + strlen( st ) );
}
```

So in main you should write

```
size_t re[n];

//...

for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
    printf( "%zu\n", re[i] );
}
```

Otherwise if you want to count substrings either `"hi"` or `"hy"` (according to your comment to the question) then the function can look the following way

```
size_t ocorrencias( const char *palavra ) 
{
    const char *p = strchr( palavra, 'h' );
 
    return p == NULL ? 0 : ( p[1] == 'i' || p[1] == 'y' ) + ocorrencias( p + 1 );
}
```

Comment: thank you  a lot, work here